# How to specify "no update" in an oracle select statement?

Tags: oracle, select

In a simple oracle statement, I have to fetch rows with no locks on it. I think this can be done through select with no update statement. Correct me if I'm wrong ? If not can anyone pls let me know the format for it ?

Comment: Clarification please.  Do you want to select rows which are not locked by other sessions?  Or do you want to select rows without issuing locks on them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you don't specify `for update` in a `select` then you haven't locked any rows.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
But my scenario is a bit different like the comment I'hv given to Rajesh  below.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want: your reply to Rajesh seems to imply that you want to select rows without locking them?  I'm saying that 40 different sessions may select the same row without any locking issues.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is only doing a select (and not a "select for update"), no locks would be acquired on the record. If you have DML (Update,select,delete) on the rows or a "Select for Update", then you have the possibility of locking.

---

****Old Answer

---

You are probably looking for the "FOR UPDATE NOWAIT" clause in Oracle, but it's behavior is not as you described.

It will try to acquire a lock on the row/rows in the select and return an error if the lock is already acquired by someone else.

Session1: (No Commit yet.. Row Locked by this statement)

```
SQL> update scott_emp 
  2    set sal = sal + 100
  3    where empno = 7839;

1 row updated.
```

Session2 :

```
SQL> select * from scott_emp
  2  for update nowait;
select * from scott_emp
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

Comment: My function is to access a table for a particular row.
There might be 40+ functions trying to access the same table.
In this scenario, will a select statement lock currently being accessed row ?...
I think it happens, so I'm finding for a select statement specifying that there will not be any update on this row, so that it is not locked...
I think it is clear...if nt pls ques me...

Comment: Hillary - Updated my post Above